# lower bounds for a stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

for all $t \in [0,T]$, consider a stochastic integral as follows:

$\int_0^{min \{t^*,T \}} f(t,\omega) dt$

where $f \geq 0$ is a nonnegative stochastic process and $t^*$ is a random stopping time.
I know such integral has a simple upper bound

$\int_0^{min \{t^*,T \}} f(t,\omega) dt \leq \int_0^T f(t,\omega) dt$

but I was wondering can I find a lower bound for this integral? not the trivial zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An obvious lower bound is $$\int_0^{t^{\ast}(\omega) \wedge T} f(t,\omega) \, dt \geq \inf_{t \in [0,t^{\ast}(\omega) \wedge T]} f(t,\omega) \cdot (t^{\ast}(\omega) \wedge T).$$ Without further assumptions on the stopping time $t^{\ast}$ or $f$, it will be difficult to get a better lower bound. Since the considered integral is defined pathwise you are basically looking for a lower bound for a *deterministic* integral of the form

$$\int_a^b f(t) \, dt.$$

Comment: Thanks for your great help, Yes, I'm indeed looking for a deterministic integral form. So what if I put an expectation on my original integral: $E[\int_0^{t^* \wedge T} f(t,\omega) dt] ?$ Then in this case, can I compute the $E[f(t, \omega) (t^*(\omega)\wedge T)]$ explicitly?
btw, the $f$ is considered as an Ito process, so I'm not sure what kind assumption can help. On the other hand, can you say more words about what kind assumption on the stopping time $t^*$ could be helpful or find a better lower bound?

Thanks for your great help again. :)

Comment: @Chung-HanHsieh No, in general it is not possible to calculate $\mathbb{E}(f(t) \cdot (t^{\ast} \wedge T))$. Obviously, $$\mathbb{E}(f(t) \cdot (t^{\ast} \wedge T)) \geq \inf_{t, \omega} f(t,\omega) \cdot \mathbb{E}(t^{\ast} \wedge T)$$ but this estimate is rather rough. If you have a specific application in mind (... as you mention that $f$ is an Itô process), it would be easier to help you if you would add all these information to your question. (It might be a good idea to ask a new question instead of editing this one.)